# Carousel Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

Eu precisava ajustar esse script para que, quando eu clicasse no botão de previous ele retornasse o comando, mas, quando eu clico tanto no next quando no previous, o slide está avançando da mesma forma, agradeço desde já.

CODE JS:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval:   4000
    });

    var clickEvent = false;
    $('#myCarousel').on('click', '.nav a', function() {
            clickEvent = true;
            $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');        
    }).on('slid.bs.carousel', function(e) {
        if(!clickEvent) {
            var count = $('.nav').children().length -1;
            var current = $('.nav li.active');
            current.removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
            var id = parseInt(current.data('slide-to'));
            if(count == id) {
                $('.nav li').first().addClass('active');    
            }
        }
        clickEvent = false;

    });
});
```

Seguinte, vou printar o que está acontecendo, esta função é o que coordena para que meu slide passe, e um background surja nas opções que tem em cima do meu menu, é como se os links seguissem a imagem

Esse é o meu slide:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas, quando eu clico no controlador para esquerda, a imagem vai para esqueda, mas o background no link, continua indo pra frente, no caso ali, ele estava em AÉREO, eu cliquei para voltar, e ele foi para PHENOMENAL, ou seja, ele só vai pra frente, não volta.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] 
Essa função é o core do meu slide, mas preciso que quando eu clicar em voltar ela volte e não adiante, como que faço isso? sou meio leigo com jquery..

Comment: Olá, Roberto. Seja bem vindo ao pt.stackoverflow. Poderia apresentar o código completo e dizer qual versão do Jquery utilizado?

Comment: Você explicou o que precisa. Mas qual é a pergunta?